# char array not displaying when passed to a function

Tags: c, parameter-passing

Why is the passing of char array not showing?
The location of the pointer is passed to a function.

```
char plaintext[] = {
         0xCD,  0x76,  0x43,  0xF0,
         0x72,  0xA4,  0xA0,  0x82,
}
```

Given

```
 void displayArray(char** plaintext, int size) {
 // int newSize = sizeof(**plaintext);
 int i;

 for(i=0; i < size; ++i) {
     printf("%02X ", (0xff & *plaintext[i]));
    if (((i+1)% 8) == 0)    // as index starts from 0, (i+1)
        printf("\n");
 }
}
```

in main()

```
        char* plaintextCopy;
        plaintextCopy = (char*) malloc(numberOfItems*sizeof(char));

        memcpy(plaintextCopy, plaintext, numberOfItems);

        displayArray(&plaintextCopy, numberOfItems);
```

Comment: How are you setting `numberOfItems`?  I don't think `memcpy()` and your `displayArray()` use the same definition.

Comment: `int numberOfItems = sizeof(plaintext);`
`printf("Number of items: %d \n", numberOfItems);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code :

```
void displayArray(char** plaintext, int size)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        printf("%02X ", (0xff & (*plaintext)[i]));
        if(((i+1)% 8) == 0)    // as index starts from 0, (i+1)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{


    char plaintext[] = {
         0xCD,  0x76,  0x43,  0xF0,
         0x72,  0xA4,  0xA0,  0x82,
    };

    int numberOfItems = sizeof(plaintext);

     char* plaintextCopy;
     plaintextCopy = (char*) malloc(numberOfItems*sizeof(char));

     memcpy(plaintextCopy, plaintext, numberOfItems);

     displayArray(&plaintextCopy, numberOfItems);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs :

```
CD 76 43 F0 72 A4 A0 82
```

Also, if you're sending an array that you want to display or change the values of, you don't need to send a double pointer to a function. A regular pointer would do. You should only use double pointers if the original array changes it's location in memory, that is, it's getting a new pointer after the function returns.

Comment: try with this modification.

Comment: Ok. I have tested the code and I will include it fully in the answer shortly.

Comment: What if I want to calculate the size in the call function?
eg.

`
 void displayArray(char** plaintext)
 {
     int i;
     int size = sizeof(*plaintext);`

?

Comment: It will return 4 since that's the size of (char *) i.e. a pointer to char. sizeof() only works on char[]. You can either keep the length in a separate variable or hold it in the array at the start or at the end. Or you can use a 0x00 to show that it's the end of the array.